# Use different loader in Webpack depending on from where I'm importing

Tags: svg, reactjs, webpack

I'm using the `svg` loader to import SVG icons in my React file.

`webpack.config.js`:

```
{ test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'svg' }
```

`component.js`:

```
import Icon from './icon.svg'

render () {
  return <svg {...Icon.attributes} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Icon.content }} />
}
```

So far I have no issues. I also want to use SVG images in my CSS. If I do this:

```
.class {
  background-image: url('./icon.svg');
}
```

My final result looks like this:

[image: background-image: url([object Object]);]

I would like to use the `url` loader for my CSS file. I tried this:

```
.class {
    url('url!./icon.svg?name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=1&mimetype=image/svg+xml');
}
```

In my CSS I get:

[image: background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,bW9...]

This looks like what I want but the image is not displayed and if I open the url in a separate tab I get this:

[image: module.exports = {"attributes":{"xmlns":"http://w...]

Which leads me to think that the svg loader is still running.

Is there a way to specify a different loader based on from which file I'm importing?

Answer (score 12):

Add issuer see: webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-issuer

An example:

```
{
  test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,
  issuer: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
},

{
  test: /\.svg/,
  issuer: /\.scss$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'svg-url-loader',
    options: {},
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's exactly what you need; it sounds like you need to trigger webpack's module resolution. By default, the CSS loader treats image URL references as relative (like they would normally be w/CSS). [You need to prefix the URL with a '~'](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#usage) to tell it to use webpack's `require` resolution to find the module.

Comment: The images are loaded, it's not a reference problem. The point is that I want images loaded from a CSS file to be processed by the `url` loader and images loaded from a JS file to be processed by the `svg` loader.

Comment: Ah, ok. You can't accomplish that with config. In your js (and probably in a CSS `url` reference as well) you can specify loaders [in the require expression itself](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#introduction), but you probably don't want to have to do that every time. The best alternative might be writing a custom loader or plugin that, during a `require` resolution, checks the file that originated the `require` and uses the appropriate loader.

Comment: It looks likeI can't see which file required the svg from a loader

Comment: @Gpx That may be true, although with access to the compiler/compilation it seems like you might be able to hack it together. Here's an example of it being done in a plugin, though: https://github.com/rxaviers/globalize-webpack-plugin/blob/master/ProductionModePlugin.js#L67

Comment: @Gpx You should be able to with issuer https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-issuer